# mmap(2) vs mmap(3)

Tags: linux, memory, mmap

Does anyone know what the difference between `mmap(2)` and `mmap(3)` is?  Man section 3 is described as "This chapter describes all library functions excluding the library functions described in chapter 2, which implement system calls."  Doesn't `mmap(3)` perform a system call?

Reading the two man pages, I see that `mmap(2)` seems to accept a much wider variety of flags than `mmap(3)` does, and claims to be able to map device I/O spaces.  `mmap(3)` claims to be able to map "shared memory objects" and "typed memory objects" in addtion to files, but doesn't mention device I/O.

Since the two functions have the same name, I'm not even sure how I can choose one rather than the other.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`mmap(3)` is supposed to be the [POSIX function](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/mmap.html). It should in all respect provide the very semantics that POSIX mandates, even if that deviates from what Linux does "natively". `mmap(2)` is the system call, and provides all bells and whistles that Linus considers important. The C library function is, of course, implemented using the system call.

To invoke the system call literally (bypassing the C library), you can use `<sys/syscall.h>`.

The actual implementation of mmap(3) can be found in the [C library](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/i386/mmap.S;h=a1481feeb55e9124e1706fb57b3e27b67d1ef925;hb=HEAD). As you can see, it usually transfers control directly to mmap(2), unless, at compile time (of glibc), mmap2(2) was selected as the "back-end".

Comment: Thank you, that was very clear.  Thanks also for the pointer into the C library source tree.  Although I do a fair amount of work at kernel and driver level, I rarely foray out into user space for anything other than test utilities, and I haven't looked into glibc source at all.  I can see I've been missing a very useful approach to a number of issues.